# Is it possible to iterate a calculation across distinct values in a column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to iterate a calculation which takes counts of people that fit particular criteria and calculates percentages based on those counts across distinct regions.

My code:

```
USE Database1;
GO


declare @ShouldRegister as float
declare @Registered as float


SET @ShouldRegister = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TABLE 
                WHERE field1 in.. 
                AND field2 in..  
                AND field3 in..
                ...
                )

SET @Registered = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.TABLE
                WHERE field1 in..
                AND field2 in..
                AND field3 in..
                ...
                )

SELECT  
     @ShouldRegister as ShouldRegister 
    , @Registered as Registered
    , cast((@Registered/NULLIF(@ShouldRegister, 0))*100 as decimal(12,8)) as Percentmet
    , CAST(100*2.33*(SQRT(@Registered/NULLIF(@ShouldRegister, 0) * (1-(@Registered/NULLIF(@ShouldRegister, 0)))/NULLIF(@ShouldRegister, 0))) as decimal(12,8)) + cast((@Registered/NULLIF(@ShouldRegister, 0))*100 as decimal(12,8)) as AdjPercentmet
```

The code returns something like this:

```
ShouldRegister  Registered  Percentmet      adjpercentmet
223587          565         0.25269805      0.27743717
```

Each person has a region assigned in the "Region" column.  The code above calculates across all regions.  What I would like to see is:

```
ShouldRegister  Registered  Percentmet      adjpercentmet   Region
223             50          0.12345678      0.12345678      Region1
456             100         0.12345678      0.12345678      Region2
789             456         0.12345678      0.12345678      Region3
```

My brain wants to do: "For Region in Regions, do (Code)", but I don't think SQL works that way.

Comment: The problem you have is you're using variables, and then you can only have one value. Since your calculation looks complex, you should look into using cross apply to re-use same calculation in the select

Comment: Please add a sample data, I think you can use one select statement for that output ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way :-

```
Set Nocount On;

Select   t.ShouldRegistered
        ,t.Registered
        ,t.Region
        ----- Isnull(,0) will cause of divide by zero error if null
        ,Cast((t.Registered / (Case When Isnull(t.ShouldRegistered,0) = 0 Then 1 Else t.ShouldRegistered) * 100) As Decimal(12,8)) As Percentmet
        ,[AdjPercentmet condition] As AdjPercentmet
From    (
            Select   tb.Region
                    ,Sum(Case When [tb.Field1.....Condition] And [tb.Field2.....Condition] And [tb.Field3....Condition] Then 1 Else 0 End) As ShouldRegistered
                    ,Sum(Case When [tb.Field1.....Condition] And [tb.Field2.....Condition] And [tb.Field3....Condition] Then 1 Else 0 End) As Registered
            From    dbo.TABLE As tb With (Nolock)
            Group By tb.Region
        ) As t
Group By t.ShouldRegistered
        ,t.Registered
        ,t.Region
Order By t.Region
```

Comment: This worked with a slight modification.  I believe SUM returns an integer only.  I had to change the SUM lines to Cast(sum....) as float...  Thanks for the help, i appreciate it a lot.

Comment: You are right, Sum will return Int, but I have apply Sum in different way for what you are trying to get count and further, more calculation for Percentmet and Adjpercentmet in outer query.